# Does the order of indices matter?

Tags: javascript, webgl, indices, vertices

```
this._vertices = new Float32Array([
            -0.5, 0, 0, // left
            0, 0.5, 0, // top
            0.5, 0, 0 // right
        ]);

this._indicies = new Uint16Array([0, 1, 2]);
```

As you can see I have 3 points for a triangle. The problem with this is that my triangle doesn't end up getting rendered unless I change the indices to

```
this._indicies = new Uint16Array([0, 2, 1]);
```

do you know why that is? Why does the order of the indices matter? And how do I know the correct order to put the indices in?

Ps. It works when setting the draw type to LINE_LOOP but it doesn't work on triangles.

Comment: What is POINT_LOOP? There's no such thing in WebGL?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I meant LINE_LOOP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If culling is on `gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE)` then triangles are culled if their vertex are counter clockwise in clip space (ie, after the vertex shader). You can choose which triangles, clockwise or counter-clockwise get culled with `gl.cullFace(...)`

```
     0             0
    / \           / \
   /   \         /   \
  2-----1       1-----2

clockwise   counter-clockwise
```

Comment: Ah I see that makes perfect sense. I didn't even remember that I enabled culling. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Order of vertices does indeed matter if face culling is enabled. What's the front and what's the back of a triangle depends on the set winding order. If counterclock winding is enabled (the default) then faces which vertices appear in counterclock wise order on the screen are considered "front" side.

If culling is enabled then only triangle upon which you look from a selected side are drawn.